# Why would an ENG camera need 422 Chroma?

Tags: video, camcorder, color

I can't believe it! 3CCD camcorders without the rolling shutter inferiority of the CMOS ones [still exist](https://pro.sony/en_FI/products/shoulder-camcorders/pdw-850) and their sensors are even bigger!

But why does that particular camera have 422 chroma? How a field news-gathering camera designed for gathering news on the field would benefit from 422? Doesn't the consumers watch TV in 420 anyway?

I thought 4 44/22 was good for green screen applications and movie making. Why would some news van people need it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I understand, before broadcasting, your signal will be converted and changed which leads to further loss. So by providing 422, the broadcasting company has more leeway to convert/compress.

See [Why is the “broadcast standard” 422 and should we be concerned about shooting 8 bit 420?](https://www.google.com/amp/s/amp.reddit.com/r/videography/comments/7utcz8/why_is_the_broadcast_standard_422_and_should_we/)